# How to enqueue multiple style sheets into my child theme in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, child-theming

I am fairly new to Wordpress but I do understand child themes.
This is the first time I came across a theme with a plugin that has its own style sheet enqueued.  Is the following code adding the stylesheet of the booking plugin into the main parent style sheet already (so I do not need to include this in the child theme), or is this an additional enqueued style sheet and I will have to also include that separately in my child's theme.

Any explanation as to what exactly and how this code is working with the parent style would be appreciated. Wordpress codex is practically useless in this area.

```
{
wp_enqueue_style( 'villagio-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), 
villagio_get_theme_version() );
    if ( is_plugin_active( 'motopress-hotel-booking/motopress-hotel-
booking.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'villagio-motopress-hotel-booking', 
get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/motopress-hotel-booking.css', 
array('villagio-style'), villagio_get_theme_version(), 'all' );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.. But, why don't you enqueue your plugin's styles in the plugin's code?

Comment: This theme came as a package with the plugin already integrated.  I need to adjust some CSS in the plugin but wasn't sure if this was a seperate stylesheet my child theme needed to pull in  or if the parent was already including this in the main style.css (through this code listed above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put that code into your child theme `functions.php` file. It'll call `motopress-hotel-booking.css` file, when the plugin `motopress-hotel-booking.php` will be active. Here is full code:

```
function custom_add_css_for_theme()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('villagio-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), villagio_get_theme_version());

    if (is_plugin_active('motopress-hotel-booking/motopress-hotel-booking.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('villagio-motopress-hotel-booking', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/motopress-hotel-booking.css', array('villagio-style'), villagio_get_theme_version(), 'all');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_add_css_for_theme' );
```

It's don't matter, from where you called your function( from child theme, or from parent theme ). The function [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) returns directory of your parent theme, even if you called it from child theme.

Comment: excellent that is what I needed to confirm.  I was going in that direction , the if statement makes it more stable.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to enqueue CSS only in parent theme, try following:

```
if (is_plugin_activate( 'plugin-name' ) && ! is_child_theme() ) { 
  //the code will show only in parent theme 
}
```

Reference [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_child_theme)

Comment: In my theme,  the plugin will be activated.
            Are you saying that I need to add the if statement  into my child theme?       Or,    Is this something I would add to the parent theme?  I want to avoid that of course so I can keep theme updates automated...     Hmmm. currently I have my child theme enqueue the main style theme   .../style.css,   but I just need to know if I also have to add   enqueue_style('motopress-hotel-booking ...') as well.  Not sure I understand your answer.